# почему не останавливает таймер после ручного клика а после машинного да?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[в чем ошибка, что при клике должен включится новый таймер а старый отключится а получается все перемешанно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1182542/%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [в чем ошибка, что при клике должен включится новый таймер а старый отключится а получается все перемешанно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1182542/%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0)

Comment: я сам ссылку дал,

Comment: Это не отменяет тот факт что данный вопрос является дубликатом. Никакого нового вопроса тут не содержится.